# What is the purpose of using CommandType.Tabledirect?

Tags: c#, ado.net, system.data

How is the option `CommandType.Tabledirect` used unlike `CommandType.StoredProcedure` or `CommandType.Text`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx) contains names that specifies how a command string is interpreted.

1. `CommandType.Text` for an SQL text command. (Default.)
2. `CommandType.StoredProcedure` for the name of a stored procedure.
3. `CommandType.TableDirect` for the **name of a table**.

All rows and columns of the named table will be returned when you call one of the Execute methods.

NOTE: **TableDirect** is only supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for **OLE DB**. Multiple table access is not supported when CommandType is set to **TableDirect**.

Sample example how it is been used:

```
OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection =new OleDbConnection("provider=sqloledb;server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI");
OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

myOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "Employee";

myOleDbConnection.Open();

OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();

for (int count = 1; count <= 2; count++)
{
  myOleDbDataReader.Read();
  Console.WriteLine("myOleDbDataReader[\" ID\"] = " +
    myOleDbDataReader["ID"]);
  Console.WriteLine("myOleDbDataReader[\" FirstName\"] = " +
    myOleDbDataReader["FirstName"]);
  Console.WriteLine("myOleDbDataReader[\" LastName\"] = " +
    myOleDbDataReader["LastName"]);
}
myOleDbDataReader.Close();
myOleDbConnection.Close();
```

Insert/Update

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "Holdings";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
                using (SqlCeResultSet rs = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable))
                {
                    SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = rs.CreateRecord();
                    foreach (var r in _commitBatch)
                    {
                        int index=0;
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("IdentifierFromImportSource",string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("SecurityID", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("SecurityName", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("SecurityType", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("AllocationAmount", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("Position", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("AnnualFeePercent", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("MarginAmount", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("Price", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("MorningstarSecId", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("MorningstarSecType", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("UserID", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("MorningstarPrice", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, string.Empty);
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("AnnualFeeFrequency", string.Empty));
                        record.SetValue(index++, r.TryGetValueOrDefault("TrackingMethod", "1"));
                        rs.Insert(record);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            NotifyError(this, new ImportErrorEventArgs(e.Message + e.StackTrace, ErrorLevel.Application));
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible, to perform Update/Insert/Delete actions via TableDirect.if yes, can you also post code of it.

Comment: By following the above code, am getting an execption:- The CommandType enumeration value, 512, is not supported by the .Net Framework SqlClient Data Provider.
Parameter name: CommandType

Comment: Have you read the Note: is only supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB..??  @Venil

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Thank you. Am trying with SqlConnection. Thats why i got execption.